# R markdown returning an error for code chunk that runs fine in R script and other code chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Context: Generating tree models using carseats dataset from ISLR library.

Code chunk (c) returns an error when trying to run the predict() function:

> no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class
>   "singlenode"...

The predict() function did not return an error in other chunks. I used the predict() function on a tree model, a random forest model, a bagging classification model with no error. Also, I got no errors when running this code as an r script file.

Not sure if this is an r markdown bug or if there is something wrong with my code.

EDIT: Edited question to include complete self-contained code.

````
---
title: "temp"
author: xx2"
date: "12/5/2019"
output: html_document
---


```{r,include=FALSE}
library(ISLR)
library(tree)
library(randomForest)
```

### (a)
```{r}
set.seed(1)
train=sample(nrow(Carseats),nrow(Carseats)/2,replace=F)
Carseats.train=Carseats[train,]
Carseats.test=Carseats[-train,]
```

### (b)

```{r}
model_tree=tree(Sales~.,data=Carseats.train)
plot(model_tree)
text(model_tree)
prediction_tree=(predict(model_tree,Carseats.test))
mean((Carseats.test$Sales-prediction_tree)^2)
```



### (c)

```{r}
cv.carseats = cv.tree(model_tree, FUN = prune.tree)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(cv.carseats$size, cv.carseats$dev,type="l")
plot(cv.carseats$k, cv.carseats$dev,type="l")
model_tree_pruned = prune.tree(model_tree, best = which.min(cv.carseats$dev))
#prediction_tree_pruned=predict(model_tree_pruned, Carseats.test)
#mean((Carseats.test$Sales-prediction_tree_pruned)^2)
```
````

Comment: Are you sure that you load all the necessary packages at the start of your rmarkdown document?

Comment: I didn't want to clutter the question by including the package statements, however, I loaded the packages "ISLR", "tree", and "randomForest". The rmd code is the same as the rscript code.

Comment: Can you please [create a minimal, self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that causes the issue you’re describing? This is work, but it’s *crucial*.

Comment: done. I commented out the two lines in (c) that would cause an error.

Comment: If I take your R code and run it in a script I get the same error message that you've been getting on the "prediction_tree_pruned" line (this is outside r markdown).

Comment: I get the same error message as you did:  there's no `predict` method defined for `singlenode` objects.  If you sometimes don't get that message, then R is finding that method somewhere else.  Use `getAnywhere("predict.singlenode")` to find where.